# Git LFS - how to track multiple file types with one command

Tags: git, git-lfs

I see this command listed on the Git LFS website and documentation:

```
git lfs track "*.psd"
```

I have several file types in my project that I want to track with LFS, and will want to track all these same file types in future projects. I would like to be able to paste a single command to track all these extensions, is this possible?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After some experimentation I found this was doable by providing multiple arguments:

```
git lfs track "*.jpg" "*.png"
```

This will track both jpg files and png files

Comment: This is a great tip, especially when creating a new repository with multiple file types.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a trick that allows you to store the trackings in a file, which is way easier to manage for bigger projects.

**Step 1**: Create a text file a list of your trackings, like this:

```
"*.jpg"
"*.png"
```

I named mine .gitlfstracks

Step 2: Bulk import trackings from that list file, like this:

```
cat .gitlfstracks | xargs git lfs track
```

> cat - prints a file to screen
>
> | - redirects the output to another application
>
> xargs - Runs a command over each line of an input
>
> git lfs track - The standard command to track a file

Here is my current list, fyi: https://gist.github.com/bdombro/a1883d8a2cd0938ef798147ba66ecc00

Comment: wow nice list! Thanks for this tip, this would definitely be a better workflow when you need a catchall for a lot of file types.

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you could thumbs up my answer if ya like it? :-)

Comment: I think the `.gitattributes` file is set up to do this, actually.  If you try J Garcia's solution and then check the `.gitattributes` file, you'll see how it works.  The instructions at `https://git-lfs.github.com/` say that you then have to make sure the `.gitattributes` file itself is tracked: `git add .gitattributes`.